# Quel auteur, parmi ceux nommés ci-dessous, devrais-je lire d’abord ?

Tags: littérature, style-de-rédaction, niveau-de-langue

Maintenant, je suis arrivé à un niveau des connaissance du français qui me permettrait d'être capable de lire en version originale toute la littérature française du XIXe siècle, mais je ne suis pas sûr de l'auteur par lequel je devrais commencer mon itinéraire littéraire.

Entre Balzac, Stendhal, Flaubert, Zola et Proust (celui-ci en étant, à mon avis, le dernier écrivain classique de la littérature française), lequel devrais-je choisir pour mon projet ; lequel, croyez-vous, est l’auteur dont l’œuvre n'est ni trop difficile, ni trop accessible à mon niveau actuel du français ?

Comment: La question ne peut amener que des réponses très subjectives, c'est question de goût. Le meilleur pour moi c'est Hugo mais il est réputé pour la difficulté de sa langue (comparable à Dickens pour la richesse de la langue). Beaucoup trouvent Proust ennuyeux. Zola est intéressant et un bon témoin de son époque. Penser aussi à Maupassant, et pourquoi pas Jules Verne.

Comment: Aucun de ces auteurs n'est facile. J'aime beaucoup Balzac, mais sa langue et sa manière de rapprochent de celles de James Fenimore Cooper en anglais, si vous voulez un rapprochement. Pas exactement une sinécure. J'approuve les recommendations de Laure: Maupassant est excellent et a produit beaucoup de courtes nouvelles qui ne demanderont pas trop de temps, Verne est facile et convient parfaitement aux adolescents francophones, et donc probablement aussi aux francophiles plus âgés qui veulent aborder en douceur la littérature française. Alexandre Dumas est aussi très recommendable.

Answer (score 1):

Pensez aussi à Pierre Loti si vous aimez les voyages et l’exotisme (par exemple Pêcheurs d’Islande). Ou Barbey d'Aurevilly (Les Diaboliques, dans un genre qui se rapproche du roman policier). Et comme les autres l'ont suggéré, les nouvelles de Maupassant ou les classiques de Jules Verne. Bonne lecture!